# Vb, SQL statement error. Can't figure it out

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net

I'm trying to build my first program and I've run into a few problems with SQL.

I have a database with customers and employees (among other things) and I'm trying to set up a basic login screen. Users log in with their EmployeeID (primary key)

This part deals with logging in for the first time.

It checks the database for a user with that ID and grabs the password. If the password is not empty / null, it shows a message box and stops there.

If the password is empty/null it is meant to confirm and then update the new password.

This is where my understanding ends. Debugging shows the error is definitely in the SQL update, but I can't see any errors...

Help?

Thanks.

Code as follows:

```vb
Private Sub NewPass()
    Dim PassCheck As String
    GetDatabase()
    'Check if there is a password
    SQLString = "SELECT EmployeeID, Password, Deleted FROM Employee "
    SQLString += "WHERE EmployeeID= " & UserID
    Try
        connection.Open() ' Open Connection
        If ConnectionState.Open.ToString = "Open" Then
            command = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLString, connection)
            datareader = command.ExecuteReader()
            If datareader.HasRows Then
                    If datareader.Item("Deleted") = False Then
                    'Password check
                    outputString = datareader.Item("Password").ToString
                    Else
                        outputString = ""
                    End If
            End If 'recordset has rows
            datareader.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception 'Display Error message
        MessageBox.Show("Error accessing database", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
    connection.Close()

    PassCheck = outputString

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(PassCheck) = True Then

        GetDatabase()
        SQLString = "UPDATE Employee SET "
        SQLString += "Password = '" & Password & "' "
        SQLString += "WHERE EmployeeID = " & UserID
        'Try
        connection.Open()
        If ConnectionState.Open.ToString = "Open" Then
            'Update Password
            command = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLString, connection)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MainMenuForm.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            outputString = ""
            MessageBox.Show("Error opening connection")
        End If
        connection.Close()
        'Catch ex As Exception

        'End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("This Account has a password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        FirstTimeButton.Show()
        FirstTimeBool = False
    End If

End Sub
```

GetDatabase()

```vb
Private Sub GetDatabase()
    'Locates the Database
    Try
        ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data "
        ConnectionString += "Source=" & System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath & "\PharmacyDatabase.accdb "
        connection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
    Catch ex As Exception 'No Database Found
        MessageBox.Show("No Database Found in \Debug", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: This sure looks like you're storing plain-text passwords in the db, and that's a really bad idea. It also looks like your queries will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: What is connection? Where is it created? What does GetDatabase() do? Also, 'If ConnectionState.Open.ToString = "Open"' will always evaluate as true. You want to be checking connection.ConnectionState == ConnectionState.Open

Comment: Is your Password variable set outside this function, or is it Nothing when you're building your update SQL statement?

Comment: I am storing plain text passwords. Yes, incredibly bad idea, but this program is just for learning basic SQL.

Comment: So that's how you do ConnectionState? I just pulled it off a forum somewhere and hacked it in. Thanks for that.

Comment: Most variables I just stored at the top of the class. As I said, I'm just hacking this together as a noob. I'll make it less of a nightmare once I get it working.

Comment: Well, the thing that jumps out at me is the Password variable. I suspected it was not be initialized.

Comment: It was. For some reason this  doesn't work: UPDATE Employee SET Password = '1234' WHERE EmployeeID = 2001

Comment: Have you tried getting the SQL string being sent and running it directly in SSMS?

Comment: I was not actually aware of SSMS :o

Comment: Yikes! Sorry, for some reason I was thinking there was a SQL server back-end, not Access. Which brings up another good point, if you are starting to migrate from Access to .net, I would recommend setting up a SQL server. You can get SQL server express for free, and will be much faster, and in my opinion, more straight forward than trying to integrate into an Access app.

Comment: Welp, this is gonna be another all-nighter. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but there's just so much wrong there, including multiple serious security issues and a potential denial of service flaw.  Try the code below. You'll need the BCrypt library available here:
http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx

First, a new GetDatabase() function:

```vb
Private Function GetDatabase() As OleDbConnection
    Return New System.Data.OleDbOleDbConnection(string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}\PharmacyDatabase.accdb", System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath))
End Function
```

It's counter-intuitive, but thanks to connection pooling it really is better in .Net to create a new connection each time.

Then, the main function:

```vb
Private Sub NewPass()
    Dim sql As String = "UPDATE Employee SET Password = ? WHERE EmployeeID= ? AND Password IS NULL"
    Dim resultCount As Integer
    Using cn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand = GetDatabase(), _
          command As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, cn)

         command.Parameters.Add("Password", OleDbType.Char, 60).Value = BCrypt.HashPassword(password, BCrypt.GenerateSalt(12))
         command.Parameters.Add("UserID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = UserId

         cn.Open() 
         resultCount = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
     End Using

    If resultCount <> 1 Then
        'If a password was already set (password field not null), resultCount will be zero
        MessageBox.Show("This Account does not exist or already has a password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        FirstTimeButton.Show()
        FirstTimeBool = False
    Else
        MainMenuForm.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If

End Sub
```

There are a few things in that code that are completely missing, and so I want to explain where they went. The first is that there is no `connection.Close()`. This is completely handled by the Using block, and handled better because the Using block ensures the connection is closed even if an exception is thrown.

Next up is the Try/Catch block. My feeling here is that this is the wrong level of code to check for errors. The wonderful thing about exceptions is that they climb up the stack. It's usually better to save your try/catch for code nearer the UI, as it's normally in a better position to know how to respond. So code that talks to the database directly should just let the exception happen, and the business or presentation layer can decide what to do with it.

The final missing piece is the connection state check. Connection state checks are really only needed either in an exception handler if you are trying to recover from an error or in the case where you have long-lived connections that you want to just leave open. As I've already said, I don't believe this level of code is the right place for error handling and .Net does better with short lived connections, so we can skip this entirely.

Comment: I'm just using this as an incredibly basic first attempt at vb / sql with no experience. The password is like that because it's not important. I'm more concerned with just learning to update a table properly right now.

Comment: This is really helpful, by the way. Thank you. Although I might leave my exploration of BCrypt for another day.

Comment: In that, just file the password part away in the back of your mind for future reference. The rest of this code still has a lot in it that's important, like taking advantage of a Using block to close the connection, query parameters, ExecuteNonQuery and it's return value, not needing to check connection state after calling .Open() on short lived connections, and more.

Comment: Noted, though I still need to ask... Is there anything wrong with my SQL update statement itself? (assuming Password is a String and UserID is an Integer)

Comment: I've tried tossing it into Access with values for each and it doesn't appear to work, but I did another one earlier in exactly the same way that worked perfectly...

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me as wrong in the syntax itself, but using string concatenation to substitute the values into your sql statement is a sin worthy of (and likely to result in) great punishment.

Comment: What would be the proper way, then? I really don't know of any other.

Comment: See how I used the parameters collection in the command object above

Comment: Aha! Thanks for this. My only regret is having to rewrite all the other forms :D

Answer (score 0):

You have the following in your code as part of the `UPDATE` statement:

```
SQLString += "Password = '" & Password & "' "
```

However, I don't see where you have a variable named `Password`. I see a `PassCheck`, but no `Password`.

Comment: Password is declared at the top of the class as a String, as is UserID (as an Integer). It's available to NewPass().